# Object not found R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to access the data frame created in one render function into another render function.

There are two server outputs, lvi and Category, in lvi I have created Data1 data frame and Category I have created Data2 dataframe. I want to select Data2 where Data1 ID is matching.

I am following the below steps to achieve my objective but I get error "Object Data1 not found".

My UI is

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Phase1"),
  fluidPage(
    column(4,
           # Input: Select a file ----
           fileInput("file1", "Import file1")
    ) 
  ),
  fluidPage(
    column(4,
           # Input: Select a file ----
           fileInput("file2", "Import File2")
    ) 

  ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel( 
      # Output: Data file ----
      dataTableOutput("lvi"),
      dataTableOutput("category")
    )
  )
```

My server code is

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$lvi <- renderDataTable({
    req(input$file1)
    Data1 <- as.data.frame(read_excel(input$file1$datapath, sheet = "Sheet1"))    
  })

  output$category <- renderDataTable({        
    req(input$file2)        
    Data2 <- as.data.frame(read_excel(input$file2$datapath, sheet = "Sheet1"))
    Data2 <- Data2[,c(2,8)]
    Data2 <- Data2[Data1$ID == "ID001",]        
  })        
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a reactive block is done executing, all elements within it go away, like a function. The only thing that survives is what is "returned" from that block, which is typically either the last expression in the block (or, when in a real `function`, something in `return(...)`). If you think of reactive (and observe) blocks as "functions", you may realize that the only thing that something *outside* of the function knows of what goes on *inside* the function is if the function explicitly returns it somehow.

With that in mind, the way you get to a frame inside one `render`/reactive block is to not calculate it inside that reactive block: instead, create that frame in its own data-`reactive` block and use it in both the `render` and the other `render`.

Try this (untested):

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  Data1_rx <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    req(input$file1, file.exists(input$file1$datapath))
    as.dataframe(read_excel(input$file1$datapath, sheet = "Sheet1"))
  })

  output$lvi <- renderDataTable({ req(Data1_rx()) })

  output$category <- renderDataTable({        
    req(input$file2, file.exists(input$file2$datapath),
        Data1_rx(), "ID" %in% names(Data1_rx()))
    Data2 <- as.data.frame(read_excel(input$file2$datapath, sheet = "Sheet1"))
    Data2 <- Data2[,c(2,8)]
    Data2 <- Data2[Data1_rx()$ID == "ID001",]        
  })        
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But since we're already going down the road of "better design" and "best practices", let's break data2 out and the data2-filtered frame as well ... you may not be using it separately now, but it's often better to separate "loading/generate frames" from "rendering into something beautiful". That way, if you need to know something about the data you loaded, you don't have to (a) reload it elsewhere, inefficient; or (b) try to rip into the internals of the shiny DataTable object and get it manually. (Both are really bad ideas.)

So a slightly better solution might start with:

```r
server <- function(input, output) {

  Data1_rx <- eventReactive(input$file1, {
    req(input$file1, file.exists(input$file1$datapath))
    as.dataframe(read_excel(input$file1$datapath, sheet = "Sheet1"))
  })
  Data2_rx <- eventReactive(input$file2, {
    req(input$file2, file.exists(input$file2$datapath))
    dat <- as.dataframe(read_excel(input$file2$datapath, sheet = "Sheet1"))
    dat[,c(2,8)]
  })
  Data12_rx <- reactive({
    req(Data1_rx(), Data2_rx())
    Data2_rx()[ Data1_rx()$ID == "ID001", ]
  })

  output$lvi <- renderDataTable({ req(Data1_rx()); })
  output$category <- renderDataTable({ req(Data12_rx()); })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

While this code is a little longer, it also groups "data loading/munging" together, and "render data into something beautiful" together. And if you need to look at early data or filtered data, it's all right there.

(Side note: one performance hit you might see from this is that you now have more copies of data floating around. As long you are not dealing with "large" data, this isn't a huge deal.)